# Strict doctype preventing access to DOM variable in FireFox

Tags: firefox, dom, doctype

I don't know if this is a well known 'thing' or something new in whatever version of Firefox it just updated itself too - but in either case I have no idea how to google for this question so I'll have to ask it here.

I have a DIV in my DOM that I am trying to directly access by id, in the most simplest form like this:

```
 alert(btnTest.id);
```

This works fine in all browsers, but was causing issues in firefox that actually led to the browser being in a strange 'broken' state.

The error I was getting was 'btnTest is not defined'. I did not get this error in Safari, Internet Explorer or Chrome.

I assumed I had mismatched HTML tags, or javascript curly braces or something else missing. Eventually after stripping everything out I tried removing the DOCTYPE. Suddenly in Firefox (v 3.0.10) it started returning the correct ID as expected.

What is going on!!! ?? Surely 'strict' mode should allow me to access named elements, and if not then why do all the other browsers let me.

**Note:** I can easily work around it with $('#btnTest')[0].id, which is what I'm going to have to do now until i can figure out a better solution.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="blueCircles">

 <head>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            alert("ID retrieved through jQuery: " + $('#btnTest')[0].id);
            alert("ID retrieved by accessing global variable: " + btnTest.id);
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="btnTest">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btnTest is not a variable. It's an id of a DOM element. I don't see what you're trying to actually do. document.getElementById("btnTest").id is valid, but pointless. You already know the ID.

Comment: this wasthe most trial possible example of trying to do something with a DOM element. definitely pointless in this example, but like i said i had to narrow down the code to root out the problem. there could be some cases where i want a 'compile safe' string of a known element's id in which case btnTest.id should be valid - instead of hardcoding "btnTest". 

i'm thinking there is a bug in firefox 3.0.10. this browser version showing as having a lower sales conversion rate too on our site.

Comment: I agree with Matthew.  alert(btnTest.id) assumes you have a variable named btnTest with a property named id, and in no way accesses the DOM.  Elements with ids are not available from the DOM with such a syntax.  That's what the getElementById() function is for.

Comment: i don't disagree that btnTest shouldn't be accessed like a variable, in fact i normally never do - but every browser as long as i can remember HAS allowed me to access it as IF it WAS a variable. so why on earth shouldn't I access DOM elements this way if the browser allows me to? of course i shouldn't if Firefox doesnt, but i'm pretty sure it did the other day. trying to go to a previous version to test

Comment: anyway best practices aside - anyone know why Firefox is the only browser where enabling strict mode disables the ability for DOM items to be referenced by id as if they were variables?

Comment: btnTest.id doesn't work for me in firefox 3 regardless of standards compliance or quirks mode. I _guess_ it has to do with document.all and IE expanding btnTest.id to document.all.btnTest.id. Firefox doesn't support document.all in strict mode. But since I don't _know_ I leave this a comment, not an answer ;-)

Comment: "but every browser as long as i can remember HAS allowed me to access it as IF it WAS a variable. so why on earth shouldn't I access DOM elements this way if the browser allows me to?"  Because it's totally non-standard, and results in clashing namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in any W3C specification that says object references should be established in the global scripting scope for elements with `id` attributes. This is considered to uneccessarily pollute the global namespace and can result [in confusing errors](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-162-global-namespace-pollution-in.html).

Firefox establishes the references when running in quirks mode for the purposes of IE compatibility. Johnny Stenback explains in the third comment on [the bug for adding this support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256932) why this isn't supported in standards mode:

> This feature does affect standard
>   compliant code that for instance
>   checks for the existance [*sic*] of a global
>   variable to set it only once. With
>   this change, that "varible" [*sic*] may now be
>   a reference to an element in the
>   document, and the code may not work
>   the way the developer intended.
>
> That's the reason we decided to make
>   this quirks only.